# Rails Postgres find attribute by substring (multiple words)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `LIKE` statement to achieve the following in Postgres:

Data: Test Project

The following search queries should return Test Project:
`test` `est` `est project` `pro`

Currently my method in the my `projects.rb` model looks like this:

```
self.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

(I'll be adding `downcase` of course) It currently fetches any variation of the first word of the `:name` attribute value but no the second, so searching `pro` would return nothing.

`projects.rb` model

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      scope :find_name, lambda { |search| where("name ILIKE :search", search: "%#{search.downcase}%") }
    else
      self.where(nil)
    end
  end


projects_controller.rb

def index                                
  @projects = Project.search(params[:search]
end  

index.html.erb
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div class="projects-index">
  <div class="container-body text-center">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <%= form_tag projects_path, method: :get, id: "projects_search" do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <!-- CARDS -->
  <div class="row cards-section">
    <div id="projects">
      <%= render partial: 'projects' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <%= link_to new_project_path, class: "new-project text-center" do %>
        <div class="align vertical">
          <div class="align-flex center">
            <%= image_tag "add_project.png" %>
          </div>
          <p>New Project</p>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`_projects.html.erb` partial

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="existing-card">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="ui icon left pointing dropdown button">
          <i class="ellipsis vertical icon"></i>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="item">
              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project), class: "link" %>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <%= link_to 'Share', new_user_invitation_path, class: "link" %>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <%= link_to 'Delete', project_path(project), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this project?' }, class: "link" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container align-flex center">
        <p><%= project.name %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html this is an unsafe approach that can lead to SQL injection. @Sachin_R approach seems safer.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, which part exactly makes it vulnerable to SQL injections? (So I can avoid them in the future)

Comment: Putting the variable directly into the conditions string will pass the variable to the database as-is. This means that it will be an unescaped variable directly from a user who may have malicious intent. If you do this, you put your entire database at risk because once a user finds out they can exploit your database they can do just about anything to it. Never ever put your arguments directly inside the conditions string

Comment: For more details you can also read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your query you just need to change LIKE to ILIKE

```
self.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase}%")
```

for more save I would like to suggest using scope below

```
scope :find_name, lambda { |search| where("name ILIKE :search", search: "%#{search.downcase}%") }
```

edited for your case

do not use scope inside method, for more about scope please see [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)
and for your case you can change your index as follow

```
def index                                
  @projects = Project.find_name(params[:search]
end
```

and change this

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      scope :find_name, lambda { |search| where("name ILIKE :search", search: "%#{search.downcase}%") }
    else
      self.where(nil)
    end
  end
```

to this

```
scope :find_name, lambda { |search| where("name ILIKE :search", search: "%#{search.downcase}%") }
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked beautifully, just to make sure now that @Stephane_Paquet brought it up, is this snippet safe from SQL injections?

Comment: Just noticed that threw an error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'each' for :find_name:Symbol):
web_1          |     1: <% @projects.each do |project| %>`

Comment: can you upload your controller and view, I'll try to help

Comment: Just updated the original post with all involved files

Comment: That throws `undefined method 'find_name' for #<Class:0x007fa9340629a0>`  [According to this](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/VendorGemSourceIndex/find_name) `find_name` is deprecated, could that be why?

Comment: Edited my answer, inside your project.rb please put your scope out from method see my edited answer (bottom section)

Comment: I replaced the entire search method with the scope line and I'm getting: `undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152708/discussion-between-widjajayd-and-dotol).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
self.where('name ILIKE %?', "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: ILIKE will make the search case insensitive.

Comment: I tried this approach and I got this error: `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
web_1          | LINE 1: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE (name ILIKE %''%)
web_1          |                                                               ^
web_1          | : SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE (name ILIKE %''%)):`